# connection Pooling in Apache Tomcat 6 causes website to hang until tomcat is restarted again

Tags: tomcat6, connection-pooling

After configuring connection pooling the website seems to hang up after a period of time but it executes faster otherwise.. Is connection pooling the cause for the same? When the website stops responding then a tomcat restart reverts back the problem? What to do?

Comment: Without some more information it is difficult to make a start on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is not releasing connections back to the pool.

Comment: Thanks Robin for your answer but in my code this has been taken care of but the things seem to hang due to the tomcat settings please do guide..